# Macro substitution in appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a variable sht= "Product" (sheet name)

I have a variable hdr = "Itemcode" (column header)

Now I want to define a new variable with the name "Product_Itemcode" (combination of two other variables) and store the column number in the variable. I could do it by macro substitution (&) earlier, like

&sht_&hdr

How to do it in app script?

My data has many tabs

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Z0Zkx4mBaniD9w9CdrhpB1GRHrkbBHx-FeOy48ax7g/edit?usp=sharing

I want to be able to refer each column by name (not by column number) like

Products[i][Product_Itemcode]

instead of Products[i][0]

This way I can insert new column or delete a column in the tabs without any need to modify the code.

Now I have to find the column number by

```
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  var tsheet=ss.getSheetByName("Product");
  var shtname=tsheet.getName();
  var [hd_Product, ...data_Product] = tsheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  const Product_Code=hd_product.indexOf('Code');
  const Product_Item=hd_product.indexOf('Item');
  const Product_UOM=hd_product.indexOf('UOM');
  const Product_CAT=hd_product.indexOf('CAT');
  const Product_Price=hd_product.indexOf('Price');
  const Product_Min_Stock=hd_product.indexOf('Min_Stock');
  const Product_Lot=hd_product.indexOf('Lot');
  const Product_Now_Stock=hd_product.indexOf('Now_Stock');
  const Product_Upd_Date=hd_product.indexOf('Upd_Date');
  const Product_Vendor1=hd_product.indexOf('Vendor1');
  const Product_Vendor2=hd_product.indexOf('Vendor2');
  const Product_Vendor3=hd_product.indexOf('Vendor3');
```

It is time taking to make the code for many tabs (with different names/header names). Can it be automated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to create the variables corresponding to the column index of the herders.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this answer, I would like to propose to use an object for achieving your issue.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const object = sheets.reduce((o, s) => {
    const sheetName = s.getSheetName();
    const headers = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0];
    headers.forEach((h, i) => o[`${sheetName}_${h}`] = i);
    return o;
  }, {});
  console.log(object)
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is used for your shared Spreadsheet, the following result is retrieved. For example, in this case, `object.Product_Code` returns `0`. So from your question, `Products[i][Product_Itemcode]` can be written by `Products[i][object.Product_Itemcode]`.

```
{
  "Product_Code": 0,
  "Product_Item": 1,
  "Product_UOM": 2,
  "Product_CAT": 3,
  "Product_Price": 4,
  "Product_Min_Stock": 5,
  "Product_Lot": 6,
  "Product_Now_Stock": 7,
  "Product_Upd_Date": 8,
  "Product_Vendor1": 9,
  "Product_Vendor2": 10,
  "Product_Vendor3": 11,
  "Vendor_Code": 0,
  "Vendor_Name": 1,
  "Vendor_Credit_Days": 2,
  "Vendor_Mobile": 3,
  "Vendor_Email": 4,
  ,
  ,
  ,

}
```

#### Note:

- Please use this script with enabling V8.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)